# Using JavaScript's replace() method with global switch on a variable

Tags: javascript, replace, global

I can't any example of this after being unable to puzzle out how it would work on my own.

All I want to do is take a string which has been assigned to a value, and use that as the replace match string for all matches.

```
var replacement = 'i';
var text = 'tieiam';

text = text.replace(replacement, '');  // 'teiam'

text = text.replace(/tieiam/g, ''); // 'team'
```

How do I use them together??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you want is to use the RegExp object:

```
text = text.replace(new RegExp(replacement, 'g'), '');
```

[Simple example of it in action.](http://jsbin.com/ufuvu)

Comment: Don't forget to escape regexp special chars with backslashes